# Paste video image to canvas using Youtube api

Tags: canvas, youtube, paste

As is show here: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/
you can paste video images onto a canvas, and do that repeatedly and you can have the video displayed on the canvas.
You can then manipulate the canvas, pixel by pixel to create all kinds of interesting visual effects, such as greyscaling etc.

But, is it possible to paste video image onto a canvas in the Youtube api?

I went over their documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
and couldn't find anything about it.

I also tried to use the same code as in ordinary videos:

```
canvasp.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
canvasp.drawImage(Yt.player,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

But I get error:
TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.